# Cheap camping in southern Brazil

Tags: budget, camping, brazil

I'm looking for cheap places to stay for some weekends in my tent. What I need is a safe place to set up my tent, maybe running water and a toilet, basic stuff. So far I was looking in places like Ubatuba, Ilhabela and Itu.

Unfortunately all the places I found are at least 50 R$ / night (16 USD) and they have all the amenities like barbecue, hot water, electrical outlets etc. Is there a way (maybe looking for different keyword) to find more basic places, or is it how much I'll have to pay?

I know camping in the wild is too dangerous here.

Answer (score 2):

I stayed some nights in a camping in [Paraty](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Parati+-+%C3%89tat+de+Rio+de+Janeiro,+Br%C3%A9sil/@-23.141361,-44.976297,10z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x9d0e3c6b68b491:0xf487f3dc51dc2b94!8m2!3d-23.2200542!4d-44.7204757), which is quite close from Ubatuba, in a camping called [Camping Portal de Paraty](http://campingportalparaty.cf/)

However, I can't remember the prices, but it was quite cheap. I can't found the prices in their website, but I found [this comment](http://ioverlander.com/places/16048-camping-portal-de-paraty) where a folk said :

```
we paid for 2 people 60 reales per day
```

The comment was posted on June 26th, 2016, so I guess it's still valid

I have very goods souvenirs of this camping, so if it's in your price range and if the location is good for you, you can go there without problem

Comment: Thanks, looks good, I'll check it out! I don't mind paying a bit more normally, but since I'm planning only to sleep in my tent for few hours I don't want to pay for all the luxuries.